# install a Laravel DataTables Mongodb Plugin

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I would like to use data tables with MongoDB database.

I've tried to search on GitHub projects especially pimlie/laravel-datatables-mongodb

composer require pimlie/laravel-datatables-mongodb:^1.1

I expect this package install very correctly because I have all requirements (yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle and jenssegers/mongodb) but it seems there are some conflicts. 
the error messages are:

**Problem 1**
    1. The requested package yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle (locked at v9.4.1, required as ^8.3) is satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v9.4.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

**Problem 2**
    1. Installation request for pimlie/laravel-datatables-mongodb 1.1 -> satisfiable by pimlie/laravel-datatables-mongodb[1.1.0].

2. Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.18

   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18
   - pimlie/laravel-datatables-mongodb 1.1.0 requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle ^8.3 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.13.0, v8.13.1, v8.13.2, v8.13.3, v8.13.4, v8.13.5, v8.13.6, v8.13.7, v8.3.0, v8.3.1, v8.3.2, v8.3.3, v8.4.0, v8.4.1, v8.4.2, v8.4.3, v8.4.4, v8.5.0, v8.5.1, v8.5.2, v8.6.0, v8.6.1, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0, v8.9.1, v8.9.2].

Answer (score 0):

You are using the latest version of Laravel and this package is not compatible with the newest version of Laravel, change the composer.json file and downgrade the version of Laravel if you could.

Comment: Open package.json file in the root of laravel source then change the version of laravel from 5.8.* to 5.5.* or etc.

Comment: in the package.json file there's no laravel version line, this line is rather in the composer.json file and in this case it doesn't work

Comment: so sorry my mistake
my mean was in compoer.json nat this line
 "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",

Comment: check if you have installed the extension in php.ini of Oracle and other packages that you need